# How to find the frequencies of impulses?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I'm currently facing an issue regarding the frequency detection of impulses. I have a program that logs the network activity of a device this way.

```
"device": {
  "mac": "b8:27:eb:5c:27:13",
  "activity": [
    {
      "ip" : "224.0.0.251",
      "port" : "5353",
      "history" : [
        {
          "timestamp" : "2019-09-23T09:34:30.898836",
          "pktsSent" : 6,
          "pktsReceived" : 0,
          "duration" : "3.972347"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]    
}
```

What I'm currently trying to achieve is to detect the frequency of an activity using its historic (or not if it's not periodic). Remembering my engineering study courses, I thought of FFT. Here is what I have so far in Python:

```py
import numpy as np
import dateutil.parser as dateutil

class FrequencyAnalyzer:
  ...

  def analyze(self, device_mac, activity) -> int:

    if not 'history' in activity:
      raise FrequencyAnalyzerError("No history could be found for the device '%s' and its activity '%s:%s'" %(device_mac, activity['ip'], activity['port']))

    start = int(dateutil.parse(activity['history'][0]['timestamp']).timestamp())
    stop = int(dateutil.parse(activity['history'][-1]['timestamp']).timestamp())
    size = stop - start

    # Array of timestamps 
    timestamps = np.fromiter( [dateutil.parse(history['timestamp']).timestamp() for history in activity['history'] ], int)

    # Array of data, setting 1 if there was an activity at this timestamp, else 0
    data = np.fromiter( [ 1 if x in timestamps and x != start else 0 for x in range(start, stop)], int)

    # Framerate of 1Hz
    frate = 1

    fft = np.fft.fft(data)

    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft))
    print(freqs.min(), freqs.max())

    # Find the peak in the coefficients
    idx = np.argmax(np.abs(fft))
    freq = freqs[idx]
    freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * frate)
    print("Freq in Hz = %s" %str(freq_in_hertz))
```

The precision is not that important. For now I've fixed it to 1s but it could be 1 minute as well.

In the activity I'm testing, there is an mDNS activity every 3 mins and at other timestamps. I would like to return all the relevant frequencies but for now I would like to get 1 frequency correct.

The frequency found is always zero. I remember using FFT to analyse signals like audio, but not for impulses. Shouldn't it be the same a square signal (harmonic decomposition)?

Here is a representation of my signal using the program above:
[image: FFT]

I'm wondering if this is  the right approach though. As it is supposed to run in an embedded system, I would prefer not to use frameworks like SciPy which are kind of heavy.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The 0-Hz peak is the average. Since your impulses are only positive, the average is also positive. So you should ignore that frequency.

Another issue is that you are not applying any [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to your data before performing the FFT. This will result in a very noisy looking spectrum. The window function will trade off spectral sensitivity (basically, how narrow the peaks are) for improved signal-to-noise ratios. An effective and very simple to implement window is the [Hann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function).

Another thing to note is that if you want to be able to detect a 1 Hz signal, which has a period of 1 second, you need to perform the FFT over tens of seconds to get a reasonable spectral resolution around that frequency. If you want to detect something that occurs every 3 minutes, then you should FFT about an hour worth of data.

If you think SciPy is already too heavy for your embedded device, then you should consider porting your programs to C or C++, and get rid of Python altogether. Another issue is that your logs apparently are in JSON format, which probably takes considerable time to encode and decode, and it's not the most compact format. Consider using a binary format like [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/), or maybe just store the packet log in [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) format and process it directly in your peak detector program. There are libraries for handling these formats for a lot of programming languages.

Comment: Not only the length of the signal is important, also the sampling frequency.

Comment: ^ which in turn determines which FFT size you should use. As a rule of thumb, I'd take an FFT size that covers about 10-100 impulses.